# Is it possible to save BBM chat in a text file using J2ME in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

As far as i know, i can use `javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection` for the required purpose. But i need an example.
Why i can't i use `java.io.FileOutputStream`, and use this piece of code instead:

```
FileOutputStream fout;      

        try
        {
            // Open an output stream
            fout = new FileOutputStream ("myfile.txt");

            // Print a line of text
            new PrintStream(fout).println ("I'm making an app on android!");

            // Close our output stream
            fout.close();       
        }
        // Catches any error conditions
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Unable to write to file");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

Please explain. Thanks

Comment: I think you can answer this yourself, by running that code on a device.

Answer (score 3):

The snipet you posted uses JavaSE classes, not available in BlackBerry.

You need to do this:

```
FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///CFCard/myfile.txt");
OutputStream os = fconn.openOutputStream();
os.write("I'm making an app on BB!".getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
fconn.close();
```

I've skipped exception control to make snippet less verbose, but you'll have to care about them as usual.

Comment: How can i access the text of Blackberry messenger? Can you refer me the relevant API for the required purpose?

Comment: There's a class named `BlackberryMessenger` that allows you to do this, but it is session based, so you can't listen for all messagesd. Have a look at the TicTacToe demo.

Comment: I found that out. All I need is just to retrieve the text of the chat window and write the chat in a text file. Once the chat is finished, can I store the text in a String variable?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The session must be started by your listening app, AFAIK there's no API to retrieve messages directly from the BBM app.

Comment: Can't we access the chat text from the chat history as described here: http://www.ehow.com/how_5867610_retrieve-blackberry-messenger-history.html. Please comment and explain?

Comment: If it is not possible to directly access the chat text in BBM, then we might do the following:

Invoke BBM -> Once chat starts, get all the text saved via key press event -> Once chat is finished, write all the text saved in a text file. Would that be possible?

Comment: It is not possible to write a keylogger in BB.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't this approach might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415113/how-to-get-text-through-key-press-in-blackberry