# How to get text through key press in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, keypress

I need to get the text of the keys at the event of key press in Blackberry. This happens when the user presses a key from the the keypad in order to type text. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the pressed key text by overriding keyChar like this

```
 public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time)
{
    if (key == Characters.ESCAPE) 
    { 
        int result = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO,"Are you sure you want to exit?");
        if (result == Dialog.YES) { 
            closePopup();
        }  
        return(true); 
    } 
    else
    if (key == Characters.ENTER) 
    {
        processLocation();
        return(true);
    }
    else
    { 
        //the pressed key is key
        return(super.keyChar(key,status,time));
    } 
}
```

Comment: So here basically you are leaving out the ESCAPE and the ENTER keys. And if the user presses in any other keys, then  return(super.keyChar(key,status,time)) returns what exactly? What are status and time used as parameters in the function for?

Comment: have a look at the documentation here http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html

Comment: Did the documentation help you?

Comment: Not much as I am not very much into BB development. All I need to do is to save BBM chat text in a text file. Here is another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173102/is-it-possible-to-save-bbm-chat-in-a-text-file-using-j2me-in-blackberry. Maybe the comments there may guide you further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This helps you:

```
protected boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time)
{
    if(ch == Characters.ESCAPE || ch == Characters.ENTER)
    {
        //Nothing to do;
    }
    else
    {
        pressedKey=pressedKey+ch;
    }
    return super.keyChar(ch, status, time);
}
```

Then you can get the values in **pressedKey**(it is a String variable you have to declare it first).